# How to delete all the Terminated pods of a kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, terminal

I know how to delete a specific pod:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> delete pod <pod-name>
```

Is there a way to delete all the Terminated pods once?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What does `terminated` pod mean? If you wish to delete finished pods of any jobs in the namespace then you can remove them with a single command:

```bash
kubectl -n <namespace> delete pods --field-selector=status.phase==Succeeded
```

Another approach in Kubernetes 1.23 onwards is to use Job's TTL controller feature:

```yaml
spec:
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 100
```

In your case `Terminated` status means your pods are in a failed state. To remove them just change the `status.phase` to `Failed` state (https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/#PodStatus)

Comment: never thought about trying a field selector with delete command, but once your see it it seems obvious, thanks @Szczad

Comment: @Szczad I've added a picture of the pods with that are in Terminated STATUS.
I tried the command you mentioned and tried it with Terminated status instead of Succeeded, But it didn't work for me.

Comment: That seems like a failure. Check your PODs for the failure reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe 2 commands:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> get pods --field-selector=status.phase==Succeeded -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name  --no-headers | kubectl -n <namespace> delete pods
```

I don't think there is an 'exec' option to kubectl get (like the CLI tool 'find' for instance).
If the command fits your needs, you can always convert it to an alias or shell function